# How are extra device provisioning profiles removed from the iPhone Configuration Utility Library?

Tags: iphone, xcode, configuration, profile, provisioning

I've managed to get 3 identically-named provisioning profiles into the iphone configuration utility, to be used for distribution.

It's due to editing the provisioning profile but keeping the name the same, then importing it after downloading it. So 3 distribution provision profiles with the same name, same application identifier, different profile identifier.

They're not on any devices yet, but they seem STUCK in iPhone Configuration Utility's library.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to delete extra provisioning profiles:

1. Select the provisioning profile that you want to delete
2. Click Edit, then click Delete (or just hit the Delete key)
3. Confirm that you want to delete the selected provisioning profile

This worked for me using Version 3.5